# Best practice: implementation of symmetric functions

Tags: c++

Given a simple class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public: int var;
};
```

and the following global/free operator functions:

```
MyClass operator + ( const int& lhs , const MyClass& rhs )
{
    return MyClass( lhs + rhs.var );
};

MyClass operator + ( const MyClass& lhs , const int& rhs )
{
    return MyClass( lhs.var + rhs );
};
```

Is it worth to implement both ways of a symmetrical function? Or just one of them - if so, which one? Is there a general guideline according to this?

Thank you

EDIT #1:

Also a possibility (thanks @Karoly Horvath):

```
MyClass operator + ( const int& lhs , const MyClass& rhs )
{
    return MyClass( lhs + rhs.var );
};

MyClass operator + ( const MyClass& lhs , const int& rhs )
{
    // return rhs + lhs; // or
    return operator + ( rhs , lhs );
};
```

Comment: implement one in terms of the other - least effort, most reliable.

Comment: Well do you want to be able to do (`m` of type `MyClass`) `m+1` and `1+m`?

Comment: There are in fact 2 points for this: 1. ppl who are unfamilar with my code do not have to worry about the operator/parameter order 2. others and I will not get annoyed of compiler warnings of not implemented overloads. This all only in case of identical implementations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say, you can write one in terms of the other. But in case the objects are really different (not two integers like here) I'd prefer enforcing some order to prevent confusions. And would prefer `MyClass + int` (`MyClass` is the principal player, put it first).

Just a personal opinion.